# PE File Injection

Tags: c, winapi, assembly, code-injection, portable-executable

I have some problem with my project. I want insert my code in any program. I explain the situatuion: My program take file (PE type) and start XOR'ed data from First Section to Last Section. Then I download in last section my ASM code, which decodes this data. I marked Last Section like (Write, Execute, Data). My ASM Code:

```
mov eax, /*I insert address of the beginning of the first section*/
mov ebx, /* I insert orginal EntryPoint (need to use jmp in the end)*/
mov cx, /*I insert number of bytes between Last Section and First*/
DO:
    mov ch, [eax]
    xor ch,2
    mov [eax], ch
    inc eax
    loop DO
jmp ebx
```

I repaired `VirtualSize`, `SizeOfRawData` (add 24 to everyone + made alignment). Also I changed `SizeOfImage` and `BaseOfCode` (here I wrote new address my asm code (`pLastSectHeader->Misc.VirtualSize`)).

But I have problem when I run my app (which I injected). Help me please with my problem :) I trying make this few weeks.

P.S My code on Plain C + WinAPI http://pastebin.com/Q4EJvM2J

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You might want to check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Formatting your question correctly will go a long way to getting you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Good luck convincing anti malware software, that you are doing this with best intentions.

Answer (score 0):

`ch` is part of `ecx` so you are overwriting your counter. Also, x86 allows `xor` with memory operand, so just do `xor byte [eax], 2`. Furthemore, you should load `ecx` not just `cx` because `loop` uses all of `ecx`.

Note that if the sections you are trying to decrypt are not marked writable, you are going to run into problems there too.

Learn to use a debugger and next time provide better question than "*I have problem when I run my app*".

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand you remarks. But maybe you have some ideas about why my PE File Invalid? I left my code in post